# due + possessive pronoun + rank

Tags: grammaticality

I encountered the bold (see below)  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiromichi_Yahara#Yahara_escapes).  [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22due+his+rank%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22due+his+rank%22&tbm=bks&start=0) attests to its use in the 21st century.

[Source:](https://books.google.com/books?id=HLUXwJVlufQC&pg=PA191&dq=%22due+his+rank%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ujqXVc6WH4OryQSDw6-YDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22due%20his%20rank%22&f=false) p 191, *Lord Chesterfield and His World*, 1935, by [Samuel Shellabarger PhD (Harvard)](http://www.samuelshellabarger.com/biography.html)

> One likes to think of him especially in the little village 
>   of Spa, installed at the Court Of London or the Golden Sun, 
>   treated with the deference **due his rank**, but mingling affably with 
>   the genteel throng of Bobelins depicted by Baron von Pöllnitz in his 
>   diverting book."<sup>36</sup>

I can't pinpoint why, but the bold sounds wrong grammatically. I am guessing that here, **due** is an adjective (and NOT an adverb).    Shouldn't a preposition be placed between **due** and **his rank**
(eg due FOR his rank)?

I read the totality of the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/58238?rskey=2mFyHN&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) entry for **due**, but it didn't resolve my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

"due his rank" is indeed an adjectival phrase modifying "deference".

The elision of "to" from  "due to his rank" was apparently sanctioned in that era. (Perhaps avoiding "due to" avoided the sense of "because of his rank"—though that's not far apart in meaning, it is different.)